# How can i build an expandable and collapsible panel in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am looking for a way to make a panel which can be expanded and collapsed with a little arrow or button. I tried to find some examples, nothing worked so far. I tried to resize a group to 0px but the problem was when i did that the panel below it stayed in a same place, and I wanted it to slide upside, to save screen real estate.

I have a bunch of labels and text boxes which provides me data, but takes up a lot of space, and i grouped them together.

All help would be appreciated.

David

Comment: Is this a web project?

Comment: Sorry. I was talking about windows form.

Comment: If you want some fancy UI effects and you strictly bounded to Winforms - use WPF controls in Winforms.  For example: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-wpf-composite-control-in-windows-forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-wpf-composite-control-in-windows-forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people have answered the question about the collapse and expand, but to answer your question about "animation" so that it really has a good slide feel.  For winforms i recommend this library on github [DotNet Transitions](https://github.com/UweKeim/dot-net-transitions)

you can then write very simple code to give it animated transition.

using the transitions library, this code would collapse the panel in half a second:

```
Transitions.Transition.run(pnl, "Height",
                                   initialValue:=pnl.Height,
                                   destinationValue:=0,
                                   transitionMethod:=New TransitionType_EaseInEaseOut(500)
                                   )
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple in window Form
Insert a button and write code

Simple Example:

```
   Public Class Form1
    Dim panelshow As Boolean = False
       Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
          If panelshow = False Then
            panelshow = True
            Panel1.Show()
          Else
            Panel1.Hide()
            panelshow = False
          End If
       End Sub
    End Class
```

You can change name of variables, buttons and panels.

**Set the panelshow to false if on application start your panel is collapsed otherwise to true if your panel is visible on startup and want to hide later by user.**

Comment: And if i want the content below to slide up when i collapse the panel1?

Comment: If you want to use animation in win forms like when panel collapsed and the additional space should be covered by that content then you can use

Comment: How about `panelShow = Not panelShow`  and   `Panel1.Visible = Not Panel1.Visible`

Comment: Pane1.visible = False or use Pane1.Hide()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use animation in win forms like when panel collapsed and the additional space should be covered with content then you can use

**Control.Top() And Control.Left() Property**  ' control = your control name on which content is written like label, textbox etc.

Or second choice

To resize your content (like increasing the size etc).

Depend on your choice as I can't see your form presentation but advise you on the base of my imagination.

**For example my panel height is 100 and when i collapsed I want my next control should move upward by 100 (Just suppose)**

Suppose, my next control is RichTextBox

Then, you can do change here :

```
Public Class Form1
  Dim panelshow As Boolean = True
  Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If panelshow = False Then
        panelshow = True
        Panel1.Show()
        RichTextBox1.Top = RichTextBox1.Top + 100
        RichTextBox1.Height = RichTextBox1.Height - 100
    Else
        Panel1.Hide()
        panelshow = False
        RichTextBox1.Top = RichTextBox1.Top - 100
        RichTextBox1.Height = RichTextBox1.Height + 100
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Just add a method in addition to our previous code to do this thing.
Don't mind my grammar mistakes.
I am not perfect in English.

For more help comment or post your code (if you have any kind of problem)